# How do people do this: http://mysite.com/#/page-name

Tags: hash, uri

I want to use deep linking on my site using this url method, but I'm not sure how it works. When I set my links to work like this:

```
<a href="/#/page">stuff</a>
```

the browser doesn't put it in the window location bar. Ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of a site that does what you want to do? It#s not really clear to me.

Comment: Your link means: 
"go to the anchor named `/page` in the document at `/`."
What were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is sometimes used for flash and ajax-based navigation to keep back/forward buttons and bookmarks functional. Check this for further reading http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/10/26/ajax-handling-bookmarks-and-back-button.html

Or you could use jQuery and a plugin that does most of the hard stuff for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin